# Выравнивание блоков css

Tags: html, вёрстка, css3

Сверстал страницу для вывода постов для категорий. И [вот тут](http://www.kochevnik.ca/category/kochevnik) почему-то съезжают блоки. Не могу понять почему.

Хотя на [этой](http://www.kochevnik.ca/category/about-kazakh-culture) странице все нормально, шаблон вывода один и тот же, просто категория другая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы используете `float: left;`, поэтому для равномерного отображения блоки `.single-post-main` должны быть одной высоты.

В вашем случае первый блок `id="post-508"` имеет высоту 380px, а второй `id="post-481"` - 378px;
Третий блок браузер ставит в крайней левой доступной точке, а она находится на один пиксель ниже второго блока...

Вам надо в `css` прописать фиксированную высоту у стиля `.single-post-main`.